# Unable to send pdf attachment with more than 2 photos using sendgrid

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, sendgrid, node-pdfkit

I have one weird problem. I created API, that allow you to: Upload photos to server, then save data to database, generate pdf with these datas and photos and then send email with that pdf attachment. It was working well for me, while I was uploading/sending only two photos. I was able to open that generated pdf file using finder, also I was able to open it from received email. 
Then I uploaded more files and after sending API request, I received email with that pdf file but I was not able to open it. It shows error that finder was not able to open that file. When I checked manually inside server folder, it was working well.

So there must be problem while sending that email. 0 to 2 photos works well, more than 2 is not working. But when I open that pdf file on server, it is working well even with 8 photos.

Sending picture of that pdf attachment.

[image: pdf attachment]

Here is code, that I am using to generate pdf with pictures:

```
const photosToPdf = [];
let positionX = 30;
let positionY = 240;

 for(let j=0;j<uploadsPath.length;j++){
    photosToPdf.push(uploadsFileNames[j]);
 }
    
 photosToPdf.forEach(img => {
    if(positionX == 570){
       positionX = 30
       positionY = positionY + 160 
    }
    doc.image(`uploads/${img}`, positionX, positionY, {width: 80});
    positionX = positionX + 90
});
```

And here is code that generate email:

```
function highPriorityEmail(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let filePath = path.join(__dirname, `../../${problemName}_${creationDate}.pdf`);
      let attachment = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString("base64");
      let fileName = `${problemName}_${creationDate}.pdf`

      if (problemPriority == "vysoká") {
        global.msg = {
          //to: ['marekzacik23@gmail.com', 'zacik.mareek@gmail.com'], // Change to your recipient
          //to: "miroslav.hanzen@skolboz.sk", // Change to your recipient
          to: "zacik.mareek@gmail.com", // Change to your recipient
          from: "marekzacik23@gmail.com", // Change to your verified sender
          subject: "Vytvorenie nového nedostatku: " + problemName,
          html: `
                        Dobrý deň, <br>
                        <br>
                        dňa ${creationDate} bol vykonaný dozor koordinátora ${koordinatorName}. <br> 
                        Boli zistené nedostatky s vysokou prioritou, ktoré sú priložené v prílohe tohoto emailu.
                        <br>
                    `,
          attachments: [
              {
                  content: attachment,
                  filename: fileName,
                  contentType:'application/pdf'
              },
          ],
        };
        

        // sgMail.sendMultiple(msg) to prevent seeing
        sgMail
          .send(msg)
          .then(() => {
            console.log("Email sent");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });

        Case.update(
          { wasSended: 1 },
          { returning: true, where: { caseName: problemName } }
        );
      }
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  });
};
```

I am using: 
pdfkit-table 
and sendgrid/mail

Thanks for help

Comment: How big is the PDF attachment when you have more than 2 photos?

Comment: With 8 photos it has 5,8 MB.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on then. Could you send me an example pdf to my email philnash@twilio.com and I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: I sended you two emails, one is with 2 photos, you should be able to open it and second is with 8 photos and that will be broken

Comment: To reproduce I will need the PDF from before you sent it over email, from when you can open it. Can you generate the PDF and send me the original, please?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I sended you only pdf with 8 photos to your email adress

Comment: You sent me a broken PDF. If the issue is when it gets sent via the API, I need the working PDF with 8 photos in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243181/discussion-between-marek-and-philnash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think we got to an answer here.

The issue is in the line

```js
        global.msg = {
```

Setting a variable that is local to the function as a global variable makes it possible that other code can change this data while it is being used. Change this to a `const` instead and you avoid that issue:

```js
        const msg = {
```

One other thing to point out, but the attachments object content type property should be `type` not `contentType` (though in my testing that didn't change anything).

```js
          attachments: [
              {
                  content: attachment,
                  filename: fileName,
                  type:'application/pdf'
              },
          ],
```